# What song is playing when Eren cries in episode 2?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

What is the name of the song about 13:00 into episode 2, when Eren is crying? I've searched in many places but I can't find it.

Comment: The video isn't available here (blocked in this country). Could you confirm that this plays about 14 minutes into episode 2?

Comment: @LoganM oh, sorry! is the minute 13:00 into episode 2, when Eren is crying in the ship.

Comment: I don't believe this song is on the first OST. I'll double-check and check the second OST as well, but it may not be a released song.

Comment: @SebastiánMolina You should now be able to upvote Eric's answer. :)

Comment: @Happy yes! I'll do it now. :D

Comment: "Shingeki no kyojin capi..." This video is no longer available due to a copyright claim by Pony Canyon, Inc..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disregard my comment on the OP; this song is on the first OST. It is called *Kyojin Shinkou* (track 9, also titled as "凸】♀】♂】←巨人"), and the part you asked about starts around 0:50 into the song.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a YouTube video or any other legal source of the track, and [the OST itself is very expensive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CAL4LEI).

Comment: YES! I found the song on Youtube, maybe my country don't have so many problems with the copyrights. Thank you so much!